# Best practices to fine-tune a model?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have a few questions regarding the fine-tuning process.
I'm building an app that is able to recognize data from the following documents:

- ID Card
- Driving license
- Passport
- Receipts

All of them have different fonts (especially receipts) and it is hard to match exactly the same font and I will have to train the model on a lot of similar fonts.

So my questions are:

1. Should I train a separate model for each of the document types for better performance and accuracy or it is fine to train a single `eng` model on a bunch of fonts that are similar to the fonts that are being used on this type of documents?
2. How many pages of training data should I generate per font? By default, I think `tesstrain.sh` generates around 4k pages.
   Maybe any suggestions on how I can generate training data that is closest to real input data
3. How many iterations should be used?

For example, if I'm using some font that has a high error rate and I want to target `98% - 99%` accuracy rate.

As well maybe some of you had experience working with this type of documents and maybe you know some common fonts that are being used for these documents?

I know that MRZ in passport and id cards is using `OCR-B` font, but what about the rest of the document?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ans 1
you can train a single model to achieve the same but if you want to detect different languages then I think you will need different models.

Ans 2
If you are looking for some datasets then have a look at this [Mnist Png Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/prokaggler/mnistpng) which has digits as well as alphabets from various computer-based fonts. Here is a link to some starter code to use the data set implemented in Pytorch.

Ans 3
You can use [optuna](https://github.com/optuna/optuna) to find the best set of params for your model, but you will need some of the

- [using-optuna-to-optimize-pytorch-hyperparameters](https://medium.com/pytorch/using-optuna-to-optimize-pytorch-hyperparameters-990607385e36)

Have a look at these

- [PAN-Card-OCR](https://github.com/dilippuri/PAN-Card-OCR)
- [document-details-parsing-using-ocr](https://medium.com/uc-engineering/document-details-parsing-using-ocr-170bf6ad8a97)

They are trying to achieve similar task.
Hope it answers your Question...!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to a ML data model that might be used to perform ocr using computer vision I'd recommend to:

1. Setup your taxonomy as required by your application requirements.
   This means to categorize the expected font sets per type of scanned document (png,jpg tiff etc.) to include inside the appropriate dataset. Select the fonts closest to the ones being used as well as the type of information you need to gather (Digits only, Alphabetic characters).
2. Perform data cleanup on your dataset and make sure you have homogenous data for the OCR functionality. **For example,** all document images should be of png type, with max dimensions of 46x46 to have an appropriate training model. Note that higher resolution images and smaller scale means higher accuracy.
3. Cater for handwritting as well, if you have damaged or non-visible font images. This might improve character conversion options in cases that fonts on paper are not clearly visible/worn out.

- In case you are using keras module with TF on mnist provided datasets, setup a cancellation rule for ML model training when you reach 98%-99% accuracy for more control in case you expect your fonts in images to be error-prone (as stated above). This helps avoid higher margin of errors when you have bad images in your training dataset. For a dataset of 1000+ images, a good setting would be using TF Dense of 256 and 5 epochs.
  A sample training dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/msawl/CNN-MNIST-digit-recognition).

If you just need to do some automation with your application or do data entry that requires OCR conversion from images, a good open source solution would be to use information gathering automatically via PSImaging module (Powershell) use the degrees of confidence retrieved (from png) and run them against your current datasets to improve your character match accuracy.
You can find the relevant link [**here**](https://github.com/Positronic-IO/PSImaging)

Answer (score 1):

1. I would train a classifier on the 4 different types to classify an ID, license, passport, receipts. Basically so you know that a passport is a passport vs a drivers license ect. Then I would have 4 more models that are used for translating each specific type (passport, drivers license, ID, and receipts). It should be noted that if you are working with multiple languages this will likely mean making 4 models based each specific language meaning that if you have L languages you make need 4*L number of models for translating those.
2. Likely a lot. I don’t think that font is really an issue. Maybe what you should do is try and define some templates for things like drivers license and then generate based on that template?
3. This is the least of your problems, just test for this.